# Wordpress Custom Function for Coupon Code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I have created a custom function for WP coupons through functions.php some time ago.

This function extends the classic coupons to allow controlling the coupon validity based on selected delivery date.

So lets say we dont want the customer to use the coupon past a certain delivery date, we set delivery validity to be 1st of December, if customer selects 2nd of December as delivery date, then the coupon stops working.

This is different from the standard function as the standard function only controls the day when the coupon expires, so if I set 1st of December as expiry, customer can order for delivery on any date and use this coupon until 1st of December.

This function has recently stopped working, I am not exactly sure why..

I presume this issue was caused by one of the more recent woocomerce updates, potentially they changed some of the functions. Will bee looking into the recent updates and debugging, will provide updates if I find anything.

Can anyone please assist me?

[image]

```
add_action('wp_ajax_validate_coupon_delivery', 'validate_coupon_delivery' ); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_validate_coupon_delivery', 'validate_coupon_delivery' );


function validate_coupon_delivery() {
    $datesel = $_POST['sel_date'];
    $applied_coupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();
    if(!empty($applied_coupons)) {
        foreach ($applied_coupons as $coupon_code )
        {
            global $woocommerce;
            $coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon_code);
            $value =  $coupon->get_meta('include_stats');
            if($value == "yes") {
                $coupon_expiry = $coupon->get_meta("delivery_based_expiry_date");

                $date1 = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($coupon_expiry));
                $date2 = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($datesel));
                if ($date2 >= $date1) {
                    WC()->cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
                    echo "Removed coupon";
                    wp_die();
                } else {
                    echo "Not removed coupon";
                    wp_die();
                }
            } else {
                echo "Not removed coupon";
                wp_die();
            }
            
        }
    } else {
        echo "Not removed coupon";
        wp_die();
    }
    wp_die();
    
}
```

Comment: "This function has recently stopped working," What do you mean by that? Does it produce any error messages, or just doesn't validate coupons anymore? What have you done to debug the function ?

Comment: Hi, it does not produce any error. I presume that with recent woocomerce updates and with them moving the coupons from WC into Marketing section they might of changed something which caused this issue. I am trying to debug it now myself, but decided to post this here in the mean time to see if someone already hit this issue or knows of any recent updates that broke such functions. I will post updates shortly with my progress.

Comment: Your question does not contain [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
maybe the problem is indeed in the (ajax) code you indicate but the code to add the custom date field to the coupon is missing... so your question is missing the full context to reproduce the problem. 
By the way, WooCommerce has a hook specifically for coupon validation, namely: `woocommerce_coupon_is_valid`